# Dismiss keyboard on the Textfield - Custom TableCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell and in the custom cell, I have a textfield where user can able to change the value. No matter, what I tried, I cannot able to dismiss the keyboard when user enters some values. It does not hit any of the delegate methods shown below.

**CheckOutTableViewCell.m**

```
#import "CheckOutTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CheckOutTableViewCell
@synthesize productName;
@synthesize productPrice;
@synthesize productOrderNumberTF;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

-(id) init;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    productOrderNumberTF.delegate = (id)self;
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // enter closes the keyboard
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

// dismiss keyboard when user clicks on anywhere on the UI
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.productOrderNumberTF resignFirstResponder];
}
```

**CheckOutTableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
        CheckOutTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[CheckOutTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell.productOrderNumberTF.delegate = (id)self;
        }
   return cell
}
```

**Screenshot of the ViewController**

[image]

Comment: Delete `cell.productOrderNumberTF.delegate = (id)self;` from your `CheckOutTableViewController.m` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `delegate` methods are not calling because of your `textfield delegate` value is not assigned.

Assign the `delegate` value inside the `awakeFromNib`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    productOrderNumberTF.delegate = self;
}
```

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an `awakeFromNib` message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.

Comment: is it in the `TableCell.m` or `TableViewController.m`?